# Kubernetes: create events for custom resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I have created a custom resource definition (CRD) and a custom resource (CR) in my Kubernetes cluster, but in my CR controller, how do I create [Kubernetes events](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/kubernetes-events-explained) which are attached to my custom resource? I hope with events, users will be able to see important messages associated with the CR when they run `kubectl describe <cr>`.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for an operator. There are already a few pre-written ones out there, check [OperatorHub](https://operatorhub.io). They are essentially [controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-controller-manager) for custom resources, watching for events and acting on them.

You can also write your own, e.g. with the [Operator SDK](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk). When you write your own, you can update the status of the CR, depending on what your operator should do, which then shows up when calling `kubectl describe`.

A good start might be [this post](https://coreos.com/blog/introducing-operators.html) on Operators, and [this here](https://flugel.it/building-custom-kubernetes-operators-part-3-building-operators-in-go-using-operator-sdk/) for listening to events from your custom resources.